# How plot bars on top of grid lines when using barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-grid

I am using `grid()` inside of `barplot()`. Because I want the bars to be plotted on top of the grid, I use the `panel.first` argument. However, the grid lines do not match the ticks of y-axis. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? My code is like below, thanks.

```
WRE <- c(1423, 41721)

bp <- barplot(WRE, xaxt = 'n', xlab = '', yaxt = 'n', las = 3, width = 0.5,
              space = 1.5, main = paste("How You Compare", sep = ""), ylab = "",  
              names.arg = NA, col = c("red","blue"), cex.lab = 1, 
              panel.first = grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL))

axis(1, at=bp, labels=c("Average Claims", "Your Claims"),
     tick=FALSE, las=1, line=-1, cex.axis=1) 
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), sprintf("$%s", formatC(axTicks(2), digits=9, big.mark=",", width=-1)),
     cex.axis=0.9, las=2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might fall inside:
 *"panel.first: an ‘expression’ to be evaluated after the plot axes are set up but before any plotting takes place. This can be useful for drawing background grids or scatterplot smooths. **Note that this works by lazy evaluation: passing this argument from other plot methods may well not work since it may be evaluated too early"***

So, probably, the best way to do it is draw the `barplot` in 3 steps:

```
# Draw the barplot
bp <- barplot(WRE, xaxt = 'n',xlab = '',yaxt = 'n',las = 3, width =0.5,space = 1.5, main=paste("How You Compare", sep=""), ylab="",  names.arg=NA,  col=c("red","blue"), cex.lab=1)
# add the grid
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL)
# redraw the bars...
barplot(WRE, xaxt = 'n',xlab = '',yaxt = 'n',las = 3, width =0.5,space = 1.5, ylab="",  names.arg=NA,  col=c("red","blue"), cex.lab=1, add=T)
# Then you can add the axes
axis(1, at=bp, labels=c("Average Claims", "Your Claims"), tick=FALSE, las=1, line=-1, cex.axis=1) 
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), sprintf("$%s", formatC(axTicks(2), digits=9, big.mark=",", width=-1)), cex.axis=0.9, las=2)
```

Comment: Thanks Cath. So there is no way to config panel.first to do the job?

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the grid to the plot after you set the axis, ie remove the `panel.first` argument and add `grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL)` after you add the axis